# How to fix: TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'Ref<any>' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I have a VueJS-2.0 application with composition-API and vuex and want to use a vuex-getter, which returns itself a callable:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex-composition-helpers';

setup(props, {root}) {
    const {useState, useActions, useGetters, useMutations} = createNamespacedHelpers(root.$store, props.namespace);
    const {hasOption} = useGetters(['hasOption']);

    const value: WritableComputedRef<boolean> = computed({
      get(): boolean {
        return hasOption(pops.name)
      },
    // ....
    });
```

The getter looks like this:

```
  hasOption(state): (option: string) => boolean {
    return function(option: string) : boolean {
      if (!Array.isArray(state.options)) {
        return false;
      }
      return state.options.includes(option);
    }
  },
```

The Line where I call the `hasOption`-Function was working as long as this code was plain javascript. Since migration to TypeScript it will result in an error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Ref<any>' has no call signatures.
```

How can I make this function call work? Is there any option to cast `hasOption` into a callable that TypeScript will understand?

Answer (score 2):

You could cast the `hasOption`-function accordingly. For this approach, you have first to cast the hasOption as a function and then their result as well:

```
  get(): boolean {
    return ((hasOption as unknown) as (option: string) => unknown)(props.name) as boolean;
  },
```